# AWS Amplify `No plugin found in Storage for the provider` error

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-vue

My AWS amplify application uses storage. When I am running the application I am getting a `No plugin found in Storage for the provider` error. Some of things that I have tried are:

```
a. removing and adding storage module by `amplify add\remove storage` commands.
b. Manually configuring storage in main.js based on this [github issue][1]. 
c. deleting the application's node_modules and adding them again.
```

What could I be missing?

**main.js:**

```
import Amplify,{Auth, Storage} from 'aws-amplify';
import '@aws-amplify/ui-vue';
import aws_exports from './aws-exports';
Amplify.configure(aws_exports);
```

**main.js: Added code to manually configure storage as per this [github issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/3505):**

```
Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
        identityPoolId: '<IdentityPoolId>', 
        region: "<region>", 
        userPoolId: "<userPoolId>", 
        userPoolWebClientId: "<userPoolWebClientId>", 
    },
    
    Storage: {
        AWSS3: {
            bucket: "<bucket>",
            region: "<region>",
        }
    }
});
```

StackTrace:

```
Uncaught (in promise) No plugin found in Storage for the provider
(anonymous) @ 4.js:241
step @ 4.js:69
(anonymous) @ 4.js:50
(anonymous) @ 4.js:44
push../node_modules/@aws-amplify/storage/lib-esm/Storage.js.__awaiter @ 4.js:40
push../node_modules/@aws-amplify/storage/lib-esm/Storage.js.Storage.put @ 4.js:234
_loop$ @ 18.js:286
tryCatch @ vendors~app.js:455791
invoke @ vendors~app.js:456017
prototype.<computed> @ vendors~app.js:455843
tryCatch @ vendors~app.js:455791
maybeInvokeDelegate @ vendors~app.js:456080
invoke @ vendors~app.js:455991
prototype.<computed> @ vendors~app.js:455843
asyncGeneratorStep @ vendors~app.js:162870
_next @ vendors~app.js:162892
(anonymous) @ vendors~app.js:162899
F @ vendors~app.js:319219
(anonymous) @ vendors~app.js:162888
TranscribeFiles @ 18.js:392
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vendors~app.js:433345
invoker @ vendors~app.js:433670
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vendors~app.js:433345
Vue.$emit @ vendors~app.js:435374
clickButton @ vendors~app.js:444622
click @ vendors~app.js:444498
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vendors~app.js:433345
invoker @ vendors~app.js:433670
original._wrapper @ vendors~app.js:438399
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the application working by

```
a. removing the manual configuration in main.js, 
b. removing storage completely, 
c. publishing the application to aws, 
d. adding storage back again and publishing the application to aws.
```